# error :column not found 1054 unknown column 'array' in 'field list' in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

this is my posts controller

```
public function add()
{
     if ($this->request->is('post')) {  
     $this->request->data['Post']['user_id'] = $this->Auth->user('id');

     $data = $this->request->data['Post'];
     //pr($this->data);
     debug($this->request);
     if ($this->Post->save($this->request->data)) {
     // print_r($data);
      move_uploaded_file($data['image_url']['tmp_name'], WWW_ROOT . 'img' . DS . 'uploads' .DS .$data['image_url']['name']);  

     $this->Session->setFlash(__('Your post has been saved.'));

     return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'add'));

     }
     }
     }
```

this is my add.ctp

```
    <?php echo $this->Session->flash('auth');
    echo $this->Form->create('Post',array('type' => 'file'));
    echo $this->Form->input('text', array('cols' => '6','rows' => '10'));
    echo $this-> Form-> input('image_url', array('type' => 'file'));

    echo $this->Form->end('Save Post');
    ?>
```

this is my index.ctp for show post

```
    <?php echo $this->Html->image('uploads/'.$post['Post']['image_url']);`
```

Comment: That's nice. Where's the question? If you _read_ the error message you'll probably realize you are trying to insert the posted file-upload form data (which is an array) into the database field `image_url` (which needs to be a string).

Answer (score 0):

I have below input in view file,

```
echo $this->Form->input('filename',array('type'=>'file'));
```

add function in controller file,

```
public function add() {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {

            if(!empty($this->data['Post']['filename']['name']))
            {
                $file=$this->data['Post']['filename'];
                $ary_ext=array('png','jpg','gif','pdf'); //array of allowed extensions
                $ext = substr(strtolower(strrchr($file['name'], '.')), 1); //get the extension
                if(in_array($ext, $ary_ext))
                {
                    move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], WWW_ROOT . 'img'. DS . 'uploads' .DS . time().$file['name']);
                    $this->request->data['Post']['filename'] = time().$file['name'];
                }
            }
            $this->Post->create();
            $this->request->data["Post"]["user_id"] = $this->Auth->user("id");
            if ($this->Post->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The post has been saved'), 'success');
                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'add'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The post could not be saved. Please, try again.'), 'error');
            }
        }
    }
```

made the required changes as per your field name.I hope this may help you.